# Method FindByName not found in type `Xamarin.Forms.View' OR Could not resolve type: Content.FindByName

Tags: c#, methods, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After adding code to a Login Pages and its ViewModel I get these errors:

> Method FindByName not found in type `Xamarin.Forms.View'

And

> Could not resolve type: Content.FindByName

This is the code causing it:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    string platformName = Device.OS.ToString();
    //THESE NEXT TWO LINES IS WHERE THE **REAL** PROBLEM OCCURS
    Content.FindByName<Button>("loginButton" + platformName).Clicked += OnLoginClicked;
    Content.FindByName<Button>("helpButton" + platformName).Clicked += OnHelpClicked;
}
```

Here is the pages content:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                         Padding="30">
                <Image Source="logo" />
                <Entry StyleId="UserId"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Username}"
                       Placeholder="Username" />
                <Entry StyleId="PasswordId"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Password}"
                       Placeholder="Password"
                       IsPassword="true" />
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Button x:Name="loginButtoniOS"
                            Text="Login"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
                    <Button x:Name="helpButtoniOS"
                            Text="Help"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </OnPlatform.iOS>
```

This code was working previously, the only change is to the LoginPageViewModel, adding a Login Method:

```
public async Task<bool> Login()
{ 
...
```

**Any idea's why the `Content.FindByName<Button>` method fails?**

It causes the app to crash obviously because assigning to the `Clicked` event when its null. So the error I see is:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image]

I debugged it back to these calls:

```
Content.FindByName<Button>("loginButton" + platformName).Clicked += OnLoginClicked;
Content.FindByName<Button>("helpButton" + platformName).Clicked += OnHelpClicked;
```

Which *appear to work* because they fail silently when I step over the lines, but I am 99% sure they're problem:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was doing this.findByName rather than Content.findByName and this helped me track it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its just a redherring. I commented out the lines I thought were the problem and turned on the Exception:

[image]

From a LandingPage I redirect to the LoginPage when users are not logged in. This other page was hitting a Object Ref. Not Set to an instance of an object.